# Adding a new JLabel through method called from a different class

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel

I am attempting to add in a new JLabel to a JPanel through a method called in another class.

Class 1:

```
public class AppFrame extends JFrame {
// CardGame
//Making private objects to access?\
private MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();

public AppFrame() {
    super("BlackJack Cardgame");
    setBounds(100, 100, 640, 640);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(new StatusBar(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(new MainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(new StatusBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    setVisible(true);
    //Does not correctly add label
    mainPanel.testMethod();
}
public MainPanel getMainPanel() {
    return mainPanel;
}
```

Class 2:

```
public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
Border blackBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();  

public void testMethod() {
    System.out.println("test method");
    this.add(new JLabel("test"));
}

public MainPanel() {
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/ACE_CLUBS.jpg"));
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(new JLabel(icon),gbc);
    ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/TWO_CLUBS.jpg"));
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    add(new JLabel(icon2),gbc);
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    //correctly  adds label.
    testMethod();
```

}

If the method is called from Class 2 (the frame in which I want to add things from), it will work as expected. However, If I attempt to call the method from class 1 it will not add the label.
I am sure the method is being called as the sysout occurs. Is my understanding of adding things not correct?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you add the label to the panel and then you add the panel to the frame and then you make the frame visible. When the frame is made visible the layout manager is invoked and all components on the frame are given a size and location based on the rules of the layout manager.

However, in the second case you are trying to add the label to a visible GUI.

```
setVisible(true);
//Does not correctly add label
mainPanel.testMethod();
```

You never invoke the layout manager so the size of the component is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint.

Whenever you add (or remove) a component from a visible GUI the basic logic would be:

```
panel.add(...);
panel.revalidate(); // invokes the layout manager.
panel.repaint();
```

So in the testMethod() you all need to add the revalidate() and repaint().

> . I am sure the method is being called as the sysout occurs

Another problem is that your getMainPanel() method won't work because you have two references to the MainPanel class:

```
private MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(); // this is just sitting in memory

public AppFrame() {
    ...
    add(new MainPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER); // this is added to the frame.
```

So you are invoking the testMethod() method on a panel that is just sitting in memory and has not been added to the frame.

Get rid of the second instance of your class. What you should be doing is:

```
private MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();

public AppFrame() {
    ...
    add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

> it will work as expected.

I find that surprising because your panel is using a `GridBagLayout`, but you never specify the `GridBagConstraint` when you add the label.